# Creating new instance of generic type converts to root type?

Tags: c#, generics, xna, polymorphism

I'm currently trying to clone a custom type in my XNA project that I call "Component", having it look something like this.

```
public static TComponent CloneComponent<TComponent>(this TComponent source) where TComponent : Component, new()
{
    TComponent clone = new TComponent(); //Create the new instance

    //Clone the source code here

    return clone;
}
```

In my project, there is actually cloning code in my method, but since it doesn't have anything to my question to do I removed it.

For some explanation on my component class, I have the root class called `Component` but then I create classes that derive from `Component` which I am trying to clone.

So for example, I might have a component called "PlayerController":

```
class PlayerController: Component
```

So if I want to clone a `PlayerController` I input that as the type argument; `TComponent` should be of type `PlayerController`.

So let's say I'm trying to clone a `PlayerController` component.

If I debug the name of the source component, which is `GetType().ToString()` in the component:

```
Debug.WriteLine(source.name);
```

I get the output "PlayerController".

So this means that `TComponent` is of type `PlayerController`, right?

However, if I debug the name of the clone, a new instance of `TComponent`, I get the output "Component". This means that for some reason my new instance of `TComponent` was converted to the root type??

What's interesting is that when I recreate this in a Console Application, I don't get this error...

**Edit**:

Testing source:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PlayerController e = new PlayerController();
        PlayerController eClone = Extensions.CloneComponent(e);

        Console.WriteLine(e.name);
        Console.WriteLine(eClone.name);
    }


}

public class Component
{

}

public class PlayerController : Component
{

}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static TComponent CloneComponent<TComponent>(this TComponent source) where TComponent : Component, new()
    {
        var clone = new TComponent();

        var srcProperties = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TComponent)).Cast<System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor>();

        foreach (var srcProperty in srcProperties)
        {
            srcProperty.SetValue(clone, srcProperty.GetValue(source));
        }

        return clone;
    }
}
```

What this outputs in the console is:

PlayerController
PlayerController

This means TComponent is actually the type of the source.

How am I not getting the same results in my project when I'm doing the exact same thing?

**Edit 2**: 
The source parameter is taken from a list of Components, and so apparently it is converted to root type when used as an argument... When I debug it's type right before it gives me the correct type. I guess I'm just going to have to make another question about how to bypass this.

Comment: What do you get if you debug `typeof(TComponent).ToString()` in the function or put in a variable to check like `var x = new TComponent()`?

Comment: @NetMage Seems like I get the root type...

Comment: So now you know the type of `TComponent`.

Comment: @NetMage Yea... Shouldn't TComponent be the same type as the type of `source`?

Comment: See my answer below. And/or add your sample code calling `CloneComponent`.

Comment: Your sample code above is printing e.Name twice, not e.Name and eClone.Name.  Are you trying to do something in your project with the clone that is failing?

Comment: @jeremywho that was a typo, still gives the same result. In my project components are attached to gameobjects so I attach this clone to a gameobject.

Comment: @CharlieMalmqvist and thats failing? What error are you getting? Do you have a sample that could show us some of that?

Comment: @jeremywho I'm not getting eny error my problem is that TComponent returns the base type (Component) instead of the type of the source, but only in that project? I'd probably have to send you a pastebin link to give you some more context, which is doable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your actual question is.  Your code seems fine and seems to give you the PlayerController like you want. If I run the code below, I get:

```
Source: Tester.PlayerComponent, clone: Tester.PlayerComponent
```

Source:

```
namespace Tester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var item = new PlayerComponent() {Name = "PlayerOne"};
            var item2 = item.CloneComponent();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static TComponent CloneComponent<TComponent>(this TComponent source) where TComponent : Component, new()
        {
            TComponent clone = new TComponent(); //Create the new instance

            //Clone the source code here        
            Console.WriteLine($"Source: {source.GetType()}, clone: {clone.GetType()}");

            return clone;
        }
    }

    public class Component
    {
    }

    public class PlayerComponent : Component
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Test";
    }
}
```

Comment: My code does seem fine but it's not giving me PlayerController like I want. When I create a new TComponent `TComponent clone = new TComponent();` the type of 'clone' is always Component, even though the type of the source is not.

Comment: Is there something missing from my sample code above? item2 is seen as type PlayerComponent.

Comment: There is nothing missing, I also get PlayerComponent on item 2 as the type when I try this in a Console Application. But in my project TComponent is always the root type, Component, when I create a new instance of it `TComponent clone = new TComponent();`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is that generic types in C# are instantiated at compile time. This means that the type of `TComponent` is set based on the (static compile-time) type of the `source` you pass into `CloneCompenent`. The fact that the actual object contained in that `source` may be of another type can't be seen by the compiler.

Since you can't know the dynamic type of your object you must use inheritance and delegate the clone operation to the actual type. In the Component class:

```
public static Component CloneComponent(this Component source) => return source.CloneMyself();
```

In the PlayerComponent class:

```
public Component CloneMyself() {
    var clone = new PlayerComponent(this); // special constructor takes self type
    return (Component) clone;
}
```

Comment: But won't this only return objects of the base type `Component` ? I see this sort of evolved into an XY problem I didn't really expect that, sorry...

Comment: No, it will return objects of whatever type it is called on. They will be stored in a variable that is of type `Component` which is possible due to inheritance, but there actual (runtime) type will be from the cloned object. You may want to read more on inheritance.